# Issue adding text after short description on product pages Woocommerce

Tags: functions, hooks, woocommerce-offtopic

I am trying to add some text after the short description on woocommerce. I have come up with the following add action but when I use it, it replaces the existing short description text.

Is there a way to add this after the existing short description without replacing?

```
function show_shipping_price() {
    echo 'Order within <b>3 hours 27 minutes</b> to get it delivered for <b>only £1</b>';
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_short_description', 'show_shipping_price' );
```

Answer (score 5):

The Correct syntax for writing a add_filter

```
// Define the woocommerce_short_description callback  
function filter_woocommerce_short_description( $post_excerpt )   {  
    // make filter magic happen here...
    return $post_excerpt;
};
// add the filter
add_filter( 'woocommerce_short_description',filter_woocommerce_short_description',10, 1 );
```

Your code didn't work well because the reason is that filter are used to modify the output.
Here is the function parameter you get the `$post_excerpt` parameter which will be displayed if not filters modify it.
If you want to achieve your purpose you can return you desired string with the `$post_excerpt` .  You just need to modify the above code i mentioned with function like

```
function filter_woocommerce_short_description( $post_excerpt )   {
    $your_msg='Order within <b>3 hours 27 minutes</b> to get it delivered for <b>only £1</b>';
    return $post_excerpt.'<br>'.$your_msg; 
}
```

Try this and lemme know if it works will for you.